# making regular expression for rewrite url with 2 parameter in the .htaccess file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

i have to pass 2 parameter to a page and rewrite my url with following regular expression in the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^chart/(.*)$ ./charts.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

means,for example when url is: chart/part1/part2/ i want to load: charts.php?id=part1&name=part2 instead of that.
i know this regular expression that i used is wrong.
what regex i should write instead this?

```
^chart/(.*)$
```

what's the correct regex for this? thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^chart/([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)(/)?$ charts.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Hope, it helps you